# laravel 5.1 authlogin where are those controller methods?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am trying to laravel 5.1 and according to documentation I added those routes:

- Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
- Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
- Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

  Registration routes...
- Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
- Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

and I created two simple views under **auth** folder:
**login.blade.php
register.blade.php**

and it worked! But when I opened AuthController class I couldn't find getlogin() or getregister() or other methods only validator and create methods, so where are those getlogin(),getregister(),postlogin()..etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `AuthController` may look something like the following:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    // Truncated some content ...

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers; // Using the trait

    // Truncated some content ...
}
```

The `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` is a trait and the `AuthController` uses (use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers) this trait and this trait uses two other traits which are `AuthenticatesUsers` and `RegistersUsers`, check the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait:

```
// Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php
trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers, RegistersUsers { // These traits contains the methods
        AuthenticatesUsers::redirectPath insteadof RegistersUsers;
    }
}
```

In this case, `AuthenticatesUsers` and `RegistersUsers` traits contain the methods used for login and registration. You may find these traits at `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth`, for example the `AuthenticatesUsers` contains the following method (including other):

```
public function getLogin()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

Also there are other methods available, check those to clarify your understanding. Also check [PHP traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) on `PHP` manual if you are not familiar with `traits` in `PHP`.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the top of `AuthController.php`, you'll find this line:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
```

And just at the start of the class, you'll find:

```
 use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
```

We can ignore `ThrottlesLogins`, as that does something else (it makes sure bots can't automatically try to brute-force their way into your system). Looking at the content of `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`, this is the entire file:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers, RegistersUsers {
        AuthenticatesUsers::redirectPath insteadof RegistersUsers;
    }
}
```

Those two, `AuthenticatesUsers` and `RegistersUsers`, are traits implemented by the AuthController, so that it can use all methods defined within them.

For instance, the `getLogin()` method is the first one in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

Answer (score 0):

All the controllers related to authentication are stored here in Laravel:

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth
```

[image]

(`ThrottlesLogins.php` is avalable only in Laravel 5.1)